# how to import more than 1 in python

Tags: python

i am trying to import a file containing an image in python but i am getting an error writing the directory name while importing.
this is my directory:
[image]

my code is :

```
path = 'file_dir/dir_pict'
rd = []
label[]
Size = 32
for folder in os.listdir(path):
    for file in os.listdir(os.path.join(path, folder)):
        if file.endswith("png"):
            label.append(folder)
            pict = cv.imread(os.path.join(path, folder, file))
            imgRGB = cv.cvtColor(pict, cv.COLORBGR2RGB)
```

there is an error: The system cannot find the path specified

maybe the file I entered was wrong name :  `path = 'file_dir/dir_pict'`

i've try : `path = 'r"C:\Users\riandra putra\OneDrive\Documents\file_dir"`
but get an error :

```
NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: 'C:\\Users\\riandra putra\\OneDrive\\Documents\\file_dir\\program01.py'
```

i need your opinion about this

Comment: That isn't an error, thats a line of code

Comment: if the file you are executing is "program01.py" why are you putting file_dir in the path??

Comment: so instead of jpg on if?

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking. Please phrase it in a better way.

Comment: Are you sure the path separators are slashes and not backslashes? Let Python handle that. Use path.join for every step of the way.

Comment: @Sayse error in line there

Comment: And what is the error message?

Comment: @Sherlock70 I've also tried backslash but it still doesn't work

Comment: Please don't drip feed all the information you have about the issue, create a [mcve]. [ask]

Comment: @Sherlock70 the path is incorrect? the file he is running is in file_dir and he puts file_dir in the path, That probably produces "an" error?

Comment: @JosipJuros we'll just have to wait for the error message to appear...

Comment: @Sherlock70 After doing exactly what OP did, This is the error that popped up for me. `The system cannot find the path specified: 'file_dir/dir_pict'` I am possitive its because he put the file he is currently in into the path to get to the other dir.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC

```
path = 'dir_pict'
rd = []
label = []
Size = 32
for folder in os.listdir(path):
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        if file.endswith("png"):
            label.append(folder)
            pict = cv.imread(os.path.join(path, file))
            imgRGB = cv.cvtColor(pict, cv.COLORBGR2RGB)
```

This should do what you want.

Comment: The directory name is invalid

Comment: @RiandraPutra What is the name of the python file you are running?

Comment: Also I made an edit, try again

Comment: I created a program in the program01.py file as shown above and I'm trying to access the dir_pict folder

Comment: I did exactly what you did, and it works. Copy my code. run it and tell he what the error is this time.

Comment: The directory name is invalid

Comment: Then your spelling is incorrect. I made the same folder strucutre like you in your image. dir_pict that contains png images and program01 in file_dir. This error is only on your side. Probably spelling

Comment: both (dir_pict and program01.py) are in the file_dir  folder

Comment: Still I believe it is on your side, bc I works for me.

Comment: i've try :  r"C:\Users\riandra putra\OneDrive\Documents\file_dir" and get error:  [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: 'C:\\Users\\riandra putra\\OneDrive\\Documents\\file_dir\\program01.py'

Comment: and also r"C:\Users\riandra putra\OneDrive\Documents\file_dir\dir_pict" and get error :  [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: 'C:\\Users\\riandra putra\\OneDrive\\Documents\\file_dir\\dir_pict\\green.png'

Comment: Still something on your side. double check the names in your code.

Answer (score -1):

The path is correct. However, to make it works smoothly, you should add a 'r' before the path itself as per the following.

```
path = r'file_dir/dir_pict'
rd = []
label = []
Size = 32
for folder in os.listdir(path):
  for file in os.listdir(os.path.join(path, folder)):
    if file.endswith("png"):
        label.append(folder)
        pict = cv.imread(os.path.join(path, folder, file))
        imgRGB = cv.cvtColor(pict, cv.COLORBGR2RGB)
```

In this way, it should work as expected. I noticed that you also missed the "=" while defining the label array, but it happens :D
For more info, look the docs https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals

Comment: This does not work.

Comment: yes it can't work

Comment: ok @RiandraPutra, can you give me the exact scenario? I would like to reproduce it on my laptop.

Comment: @AndreaBarra Try to replicate what I did in my question. And let me know if you still have the error

Comment: Hi guys, I tried to replicate what @JosipJuros suggested, and I confirm what he is saying. The code he provided is working. Just be sure of what we are talking about, I created a new folder on my Dekstop called 'file_dir' and I added inside this folder the script alongside the folder called 'dir_pict'. Dir_pict contains a dummy png file I had in local env. Reproducing those steps I don't encounter any exception running Josip's code.